# Is there a simple way to make sense of Ethereum tx given ABI?

Tags: web3js, abi

It seems that ABI is used by web3.js to only make sense of the function calls and storage values, are there any simple means to make sense of Ethereum tx given ABI?

For example, given ABI, is there an easy way, perhaps via web3.js, to make sense of [this tx](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x833bcb0e5b2a3f8e9b6670d7199b9c43d8e7295d76fd3111ef0701671a642c76)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools could be written and explorers could add functionality to make it easier to understand transactions.  Having the ABI and source code will help present a clearer picture.

Here is a manual process for now for tx [0x833bcb0e5b2a3f8e9b6670d7199b9c43d8e7295d76fd3111ef0701671a642c76](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x833bcb0e5b2a3f8e9b6670d7199b9c43d8e7295d76fd3111ef0701671a642c76)

The first 4 bytes of the input data in the tx specifies which function is invoked.  https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x4636a159 suggests it is `newPhoneToAddr(address,uint256)`.  The next 32 bytes in the input are then the address, and the 32 bytes after is the uint256 parameter to `newPhoneToAddr(address,uint256)`.  This sounds like the transaction registered a phone number to an address.  The source code [to the contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0xf7e9626dbaeb1a6c8b3d02379eb54b81f16e785f) would help to ascertain further details.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and it looks like it's possible to be added as a part of web3.js providing something like `getTransaction(hash, abi)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That could be possible if you're just looking for what was the initial function invoked and the parameters.

Comment: That sounds like the reverse of `myContract.myFunction.getData(param1, param2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder

its a tool that does exactly that, you provide an ABI then a transaction 
and you get everything decoded and parsed in return